# Write works but Read fails- C

Tags: c, file-io

I have the following code that gets the filepath from another module, opens the file and reads the content. The file is opening , but read fails with error: Bad file number. I then inserted a write command after open, which works, but read still fails.Can someone please tell me why read isnt working? Also , Im puzzled about why write() even works when im opening the file in R_ONLY mode.

```
          char* file_content = (char*) malloc (1024);
          int fd = open(filepath,"O_RDONLY");
          printf("I have attempted open file \n");
          fflush(stdout);
          bzero(file_content, 1024*sizeof(char));
          if(fd <= 0) { //open failed
            file_content = "Error opening file";
            printf("The error number is %d\n", errno);
            fflush(stdout);
          }
          else
          {
             if(write(fd, "hello", 5)<0){
                printf("write failed");
                fflush(stdout);
              }
            if(read(fd, file_content,1023) < 0){
                printf("Error! Read file as %d\n",errno);
                fflush(stdout);
            }
          }
```

Output is Error! Read file as 8. 8=Bad file number. Any help please?

Comment: `open(filepath,"O_RDONLY");` - you are in the most serious need of reading the man page for `open()`.

Comment: `(char*) malloc (1024)` - you are in the most serious need of reading [the reasoning in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858) about the harmful nature of that superfluous cast.

Comment: How did that even compile in the first place?!

Comment: @JustSid no reason it wouldn't compile.  it will just use the address of the string as an `int` while looking for the open flags.  c is very 'forgiving'

Comment: -wall is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is

```
open(filepath,"O_RDONLY");
```

should be

```
open(filepath, O_RDONLY);
```

currently it is using the address of the string literal as the integer for the open flags.